# React : How to pass values from grandchild through child to parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent,child and grandchild component. I have different input fields and want to pass the values from grandchild to child to parent where eventually i set the state with the values. I havent included all of my code, but doing it like that is necessary because of other things in my code, which I didnt include in this post as its irrelevant. Im not sure how to do that and tried to implement what I found online, however, its not working. Any ideas? Thanks!!

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        input: {}
    };
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
}

changeName(newName) {
    this.setState({
        name: newName
    });
}
handleInput() {
    console.log("helloooooo", this.state.name)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Child onChange={this.changeName} onClick={this.handleInput}/>
        </div>
    )
}
}

class Child extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInput2 = this.handleInput2.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
    this.props.handleChange(e);
}

handleInput2() {
    this.props.onClick()
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <GrandChild onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleInput2}/>
        </div>
        )
}
}

class GrandChild extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInput2 = this.handleInput2.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
    const input = this.props.input;
    input[name] = e.target.value;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input name="firstname" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input name="lastname" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This breaks a huge part of component isolation. Composed components should not be communicating with parents, they shouldn't even be "aware" of parent components. The parent *can control the child* but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

In real life everything is easier. For every component you answer following questions.

> What data the component will receive? 
>   Does it emit any event?
>
> That's the `props` of the component.

So no matter how the relationship between your components is... Just answer those questions and you will be good.

**Example:**

I have a `TodoList` that contains a list of `TodoItem` elements. (Parent)

I have a `TodoItem` that displays the content of the TodoItem. (Child)

I have a `Checkbox` that displays a check box. (GrandChild)

a `CheckBox` receives a boolean saying `isSelected` and emit and event `onChange`. That's all what I know.

a `TodoItem` receives a `Todo` and emit `onChange`. That's all I care.

When you put everything together, `TodoList` has a `todos`, and pass `todos[i]` to its child and `todos[i].isSelected` to its grandchild, but that is what you don't need to care about. All what you care is:

> What data the component will receive? Does it emit any event?

At the component level.